# How to specify paths in JMeter tests installation independent

Tags: configuration, path, jmeter

[This description of the CSV Data SetConfig](http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/) describes that the path to a CSV file used for importing parameters should reside in the bin directory of the JMeter installation, or the path specified should be relative to that bin directory:

> Save that file in the bin directory where your JMeter installation lives.

Since the installation path of JMeter is potentially (and in my case actually) different on the various machines involved, this is rather awkward.

What is the preferred way to specify such paths in a way that is independent of the installation directories and the directory the test is stored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that article was wrong. By accident I found out that JMeter seems to consider paths relative to the testscript it has loaded. So no need to put anything in the `bin` directory of JMeter itself.

Of course if you can't (or don't want) to use relative paths like that either, [UBIK LOAD PACKs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31019974/66686) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

- in your path use [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function

> __P(datadir)/file1.csv

- When starting JMeter, pass value using -Jdatadir=<your full path to data directory>, see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override